How can I add preloader in my custom wordpress theme?
I'm trying to add preloader on my theme. When I'm using this code in functions.php then It work fine. But I'm not interest use CSS & JS on functions.php
Please help me.
add_action('init', 'Devnuru_Preloader');
function Devnuru_Preloader()
{
  if (! is_admin() &&  $GLOBALS["pagenow"] !== "wp-login.php") {

    $delay = 1;  //seconds
    $loader = 'http://devnuru.local/wp-content/uploads/2024/09/devnuru-spinner.svg';
    $overlayColor = '#ffffff';
    echo '<div class="Preloader"><img 

src="' . $loader . '" alt="" style="height: 150px;"></div>

 <style>
.Preloader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: ' . $overlayColor . ';
  z-index: 100000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
</style>

<script>
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
document.addEventListener

("DOMContentLoaded", () => setTimeout( function() { 

document.querySelector("div.Preloader").remove(); 

document.body.style.overflow = "visible"; } , ' . $delay . ' * 1000));
</script>
';
  }
}

When I'm putting HTML Code in my footer & CSS code in my main CSS file & JS code in JS file then It's not working.

add loader to header
add_action('wp_head', 'loader');
function loader(){
?>
   <div class="loader"></div>
   <style>style here</style>
   <script>your code here</script>
<?php
};


If you don't mind hard-coding the variable values into your theme:
For the page:
<div class="Preloader"><img src="//devnuru.local/wp-content/uploads/2024/09/devnuru-spinner.svg" alt="" style="height: 150px;"></div>

<script>
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
document.addEventListener

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => setTimeout(() => {

    document.querySelector("div.Preloader").remove();

    document.body.style.overflow = "visible";
}, 1000));
</script>

For the css file:
.Preloader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 100000;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }

Don't forget to reload the script from the source in your browser with a hard refresh.

You can add via functions.php file of your theme. Here is the code:
functions.php
function add_preloader_html() {
    ?>
    <!-- Preloader -->
    <div id="preloader">
        <div id="loader"></div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_body_open', 'add_preloader_html');

// Add JavaScript to hide the preloader
function add_preloader_script() {
    ?>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            // Hide the preloader when the page is fully loaded
            window.addEventListener("load", function() {
                var preloader = document.getElementById('preloader');
                if (preloader) {
                    preloader.style.display = 'none';
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_preloader_script');

style.css
/* Preloader styles */
#preloader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 9999;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#loader {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

